# Having Issues with MUI DataGrid export to csv functionality. How can I get good data inserted into the excel sheet instead of [Object object]?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, material-ui

I am running into a issue when exporting to CSV. Instead of the actual value, I am getting [Object object]. I am currently using the valueGetter based on what I read from the docs but it still is not working.

here is what the code looks like, this object is inside of a fields array:

{
name: "myMetrics",
component: ,
width: 275,
flex: 1,
valueGetter: (params) => params.row.myMetrics
},

anyone have an idea on how I can get the actual value when exporting to csv?

Comment: you need to `JSON.stringify(THE FIELD VALUE)` inside your `valueGetter()` function. Like this `JSON.stringify(params.row.myMetrics)` instead of just `params.row.myMetrics`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when trying to display dates. What I did was use valueFormatter like this

```
valueFormatter: (params) => moment(params.value).format("MM/DD/YY")
```

and that fixed the [object, object] display in my csv exports.